# adding other modules in classpath for a Gradle plugin task

Tags: gradle, gradle-plugin

I have a Gradle plugin that works well so far, however, I am facing an issue in a multi-module project.

The plugin runs its task in every module of the project, but sometimes, I need to access classes from other modules to analyze them - typically, in the context of hexagonal architecture, I want to perform some checks on classes in `infrastructure` that implement an interface defined in `domain` module.

So, when the task runs (after the tests) within `infrastructure` module, it finds the class. But it's not able to load the interface (from `domain`) that the class implements. When I do :

```
Object interfaceLoadedDynamically = Class.forName(i.getName());
```

I clearly see it can't be loaded, and that prevents me from performing the checks I need to do.

here are :

- [the plugin](https://github.com/societe-generale/arch-unit-gradle-plugin/blob/c1af2ed56cff834dfbe7336e907029889e684401/src/main/java/com/societegenerale/commons/plugin/gradle/ArchUnitGradlePlugin.java)
- [the task](https://github.com/societe-generale/arch-unit-gradle-plugin/blob/c1af2ed56cff834dfbe7336e907029889e684401/src/main/java/com/societegenerale/commons/plugin/gradle/ArchUnitRulesTask.java)

Is there a way to configure one of them to say : "*when you run within a module, make sure all the other project modules that have been compiled before are available in the classpath*" ?

I've seen maybe I could use Gradle's [Configuration](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.Configuration.html) , but I am really not sure where/how to start.